# CURL request at No Internet in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am working with CURL request in PHP. My code is like below.

```
        // init curl object
        $ch = curl_init();

        // define options
        $option_array = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $api_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1
        );
        
        // apply options
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $option_array);

        // execute request and get response
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
        } else {
            return $response;        
        }

        curl_close($ch);
```

How to know internet is not available at CURL request in PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [CURL Error List](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) you will face `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)`.

```
if (curl_errno($ch) === 7) {
    throw new Exception('No Internet.');
}
```

Comment: That is what I've stumbled upon, too. There is also a post on the php.net manual: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-errno.php#103128 which lists some error codes.

Comment: But be aware this is a user note.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusZeller. But how to know about other errors ?

Comment: I've put a link in my answer to the curl error list. https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html Also the PHP documentation refers that.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusZeller. I checked your link previously. But I need some explanation of the errors. What are other causes of error ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what exactly you want know. If curl fails, you get an int as error number. Looking up the number you can see what the cause was or even use the curl_error() method to see a text error message. Your question is `How to know internet is not available at CURL request in PHP?` and this answered. You know, if error number is 7.